# Cantor set and triadic expansions

Tags: fractals, cantor-set

I'm trying to prove that the Cantor set is equal to a certain set of 'escape points' for a mathematical feedback system.

In this proof I'm going to need the fact that every element of the Cantor set has a base-3 representation in which only 0's and 2's occur. However, I'm having a hard time with these triadic expansions. Can you help me by working out an easier problem (also using triadic expansions)?

> If $x$ is in the Cantor set, then so is $1-x$.

I don't know if there is an easier way to prove this, but I'm specifically looking for a proof using the fact that x can be written as $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ where $a_i$ is either $0$ or $2$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that every element of the Cantor set doesn't have a 1? If so, note that each "left" in the Cantor tree is a 0 in the ternary expansion while each "right" is a 2. Thus it can happen that a number in the Cantor set has a ternary expansion with a 1...but in this case there is a different expansion that ends in infinitely many 2s.

Comment: Remember that $1=.222\dots_3$.

Comment: @Ian This proof I already understand. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for the tip, it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$, where the expansion is ternary and each $a_k$ is $0$ or $2$. For $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $b_k=2-a_k$; clearly $b_k\in\{0,2\}$. Let $y=0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots\;$; then $x+y=0.222\ldots=1$, so $y=1-x$ is in the Cantor set.

(I can recast this in terms of infinite series if you like, but this should be sufficient.)

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, it helped!

Comment: @Kaspar: You’re welcome!